# Can you erase text that a turtle has made in python

Tags: python, text, turtle-graphics

So I want to write text using turtle. Once I have written it, I want to erase it. can you do anything to erase it?

```
turtle.write('hello world', font=('Arial',12','normal)
```

whats next?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation. The function clear, removes the turtle's drawings. https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.clear

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to erase everything the turtle wrote, just the text?

Comment: The best way I can think of is to use a different turtle to draw the text, and then clear the second turtle's drawing (clearing the text, keeping all other turtle's drawings.

Comment: I only wanted to erase one thing the turtle wrote not everything

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. First make assign the turtle.write to a variable maybe something like this...

```
text = turtle.Turtle()
text.write('hello world', font=('Arial',12','normal)
```

Then all you need to do is run

```
text.clear()
```

That will clear the text variable which is the text on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update (erase and rewrite) text, I recommend a dedicated turtle instance for the purpose.  Regardless, you can use `.clear()`, to clear everything, or `.undo()` to just clear the last thing the turtle wrote (assuming no other undoable actions inbetween.)